# How to target a linked image instead of linked text in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to target a linked image instead of linked text, which is the way it's coded in the following code snippet using the `textContent` property on this page: [www.ninjasdontsweat.com](http://www.ninjasdontsweat.com). The way I understand it is the search is activated when the page loads and adds a `className` 'sqs-search-ui-button sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper' to the element surrounding the search text (in this case the <li> element).

```
<script>
//SEARCH
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var nav = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav .external-link");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nav,function(el,i){
        if (el.textContent.match(/Search/)) {
            el.className += ' sqs-search-ui-button sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper';
        }
    });
});
</script>

<li class="external-link sqs-search-ui-button sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper">
      <a href="/Search">Search</a>
</li>
```

On my page (see below), basically what I think needs to happen is this: when search.jpg is clicked, the JavaScript will do two things...add the `className` "sqs-search-ui-button sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper" to the <a> element and deactivate the href "/nandf/" allowing the CSS to overlay the page as it does in the first code snippet. Hope that makes sense! Let me know if you have any questions.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  
         <a class="project " href="/nandf/" data-ajaxify="false">
           <div>
            <div class="project-image"><div class="intrinsic">
             <div class="content-fill" style="overflow: hidden;">
               <img data-src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52cd716be4b065c5e52b9967/t/53248d81e4b0d7985481f99d/1394904442216/search.jpg" 
               data-image="http://static.squarespace.com/static/52cd716be4b065c5e52b9967/t/53248d81e4b0d7985481f99d/1394904442216/search.jpg" 
               data-image-dimensions="396x396" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" 
               data-load="false" alt="search" 
               class="" src="https://static.squarespace.com/static/52cd716be4b065c5e52b9967/t/53248d81e4b0d7985481f99d/1394904442216/search.jpg?format=300w" 
               data-image-resolution="300w" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 282px; height: 282px; position: relative;"></div></div><div class="project-item-count">1</div></div>
            <div class="project-title">search</div>
           </div>
        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? It would be a lot easier to give whatever element you want to _trigger_ the search an id, and target it by that specifically in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for images inside the element as well:

```
var nav = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav .external-link");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(nav,function(el,i){
  if(matches(el)) {
    el.className += ' sqs-search-ui-button sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper';
  }
});

function matches(el) {
  if (el.textContent.match(/Search/)) {
    return true;
  }

  var images = el.getElementsByTagName("img");
  return Array.prototype.some.call(images, function(img) {
    return img.src.match(/search/);
  });
}
```

If you have more criteria (e.g. matching the image's `title`), you just need to add them to the `matches` function.

Comment: Hi Renato, sorry about not getting back to you sooner and thanks for the answer. Your solution isn't working for me for some reason. What I'd like is the image search.jpg to open up the search page as it does on this example: http://www.ninjasdontsweat.com/ In the ninja site the search opens with the search link in the nav. But I'd like search to activate when search.jpg is clicked. Do you think your solution does that? Thanks again!